# Get private Properties/Method of base-class with reflection

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

With `Type.GetProperties()` you can retrieve all properties of your current class and the `public` properties of the base-class. Is it somehow possible to get the `private` properties of the base-class too?

```
class Base
{
    private string Foo { get; set; }
}

class Sub : Base
{
    private string Bar { get; set; }
}

Sub s = new Sub();
PropertyInfo[] pinfos = s.GetType().GetProperties(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Static);
foreach (PropertyInfo p in pinfos)
{
    Console.WriteLine(p.Name);
}
Console.ReadKey();
```

This will only print "Bar" because "Foo" is in the base-class and private.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

To get all properties (public/private/protected/internal/static/instance) of a given `Type someType`, you must access the base class by using `someType.BaseType`.

Example:

```
PropertyInfo[] props = someType.BaseType.GetProperties(
        BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Public
        | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Static)
```

Comment: In addition, it is possible to iterate through the base types (type = type.BaseType), until type.BaseType is null, to get a complete picture.

Comment: unfortunately this does not work for private properties of the base class. only for inherited public and protected

Comment: @Fabiano - nonpublic includes private.

Comment: @Marc Gravell it seems that this only includes privates of the subclass but not of the baseclass. See additional information at the question

Comment: @Fabiano You need to call GetProperties() off of s.GetType().BaseType, not off of just GetType().

Comment: ok, so it seems you can't get all properties at once but have to check all basetypes by hand. But this will do it. Thanks

Comment: Why I have to call BaseType in case of private properties?

Comment: @honzakuzel1989 because the question here is "of base class", meaning it is the `BaseType` that declares them

Answer (score 5):

Iterate through the base types (type = type.BaseType), until type.BaseType is null.

```
MethodInfo mI = null;
Type baseType = someObject.GetType();
while (mI == null)
{
    mI = baseType.GetMethod("SomePrivateMethod", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
    baseType = baseType.BaseType;
    if (baseType == null) break;
}
mI.Invoke(someObject, new object[] {});
```