# How to access a private base class field using Reflection

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, types, casting

I'm trying to set the private "visible" field on a variable of type BaseClass.

- ChildClass

  - BaseClass

    - "visible" field

I've successfully accessed the variable of type ChildClass, and the FieldInfo for the "visible" field on the BaseClass.

But when I try to set/get the value of the field, I get the error **System.Runtime.Remoting.RemotingException: Remoting cannot find field 'visible' on type 'BaseClass'.**

So Is there a way to "down cast" a variable of type ChildClass to BaseClass in order for the reflection to work?

---

**Edit:** The exact code I'm using:

```
// get the varible
PropertyInfo pi = overwin.GetProperty("Subject", BindingFlags.Instance|BindingFlags.Public);
CalcScene scene = (CalcScene) pi.GetValue(inwin, null);

// <<< scene IS ACTUALLY A TYPE OF DisplayScene, WHICH INHERITS FROM CalcScene

// get the 'visible' field
Type calScene = typeof(CalcScene);
FieldInfo calVisible = calScene.GetField("visible",BindingFlags.Instance|BindingFlags.NonPublic);

// set the value
calVisible.SetValue(scene, true); // <<< CANNOT FIND FIELD AT THIS POINT
```

The exact class structure:

```
class CalcScene  
{
    private bool visible;
}

class DisplayScene : CalcScene  
{
}
```

Comment: Can you post definitions for your classes, and the reflection code you're using?

Comment: You seem to be conflating the terms "property" and "field" in your question.  Are you sure you're looking for the right thing?

Comment: You are intermixing the term field and property in your question. They are different concepts and Reflection provides different methods for accessing their definitions (GetProperties() vs GetFields() for instance). My guess is that your visible field is actually defined as a property.

Comment: If you have an instance of CalcScene, why not make a public Visible property and don't use Reflection?

Comment: @jrummell - I'm using reflection to edit values in a 3rd party component I'm using. And so I obviously cannot change the source code!

Comment: That sounds very fragile. Any changes in the component could break your code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can try like this

```
    class B
    {
        public int MyProperty { get; set; }
    }

    class C : B
    {
        public string MyProperty2 { get; set; }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        PropertyInfo[] info = new C().GetType().GetProperties();
        foreach (PropertyInfo pi in info)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(pi.Name);
        }
    }
```

produces

```
    MyProperty2
    MyProperty
```

Comment: What if both properties are private?

Comment: @Jenko would you pls take a look at this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2267277/get-private-properties-method-of-base-class-with-reflection

Comment: Does it work? I've tried and i could not make it work. Do you have any more info? I'm getting the error "Remoting cannot find field "visible" on type BaseClas" ... do you know why?

Answer (score 1):

Here is some code that demonstrates the difference between getting a field vs a property:

```
  public static MemberInfo GetPropertyOrField(this Type type, string propertyOrField)
  {
      MemberInfo member = type.GetProperty(propertyOrField, BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.IgnoreCase);
      if (member == null)
          member = type.GetField(propertyOrField, BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.IgnoreCase);

      Debug.Assert(member != null);
      return member;
  }
```

Comment: Thanks, but the FieldInfo is a non-null value! I've already been able to access the field for the "visible" property!

Comment: Oh I see. You are trying to set a private field value on a base class using reflection. Didn't catch that. Is your code fully trusted and/or have the correct permissions? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6z33zd7h.aspx