# C# Why are private methods not shown in this reflection example

Tags: c#, reflection

I am learning C# and was trying a simple Reflection Example. I am trying to get the names of methods from a class. Here's The code:

```
using System;
using System.Reflection;

namespace Practice
{
    class ReflectionExamples
    {
        private int Sum(int a, int b)
        {
            return a + b;
        }

        public int GetSum(int a, int b)
        {
            int c = Sum(a, b);

            return c;

        }
    }

    class ReflectionDemo
    {
        public static void Execute() // Main calls this
        {
            var a = typeof(ReflectionExamples);

            MethodInfo[] mi = a.GetMethods(); //Using BindingFlags.NonPublic does not show any results
            foreach (MethodInfo m in mi)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(m.Name);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The output from this is(Sum is missing):

```
GetNum
ToString
Equals
GetHashCode
GetType
```

Comment: Try `BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance` [Demo](https://ideone.com/jUyfUN)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2267277/get-private-properties-method-of-base-class-with-reflection

Comment: `GetMethods` without parameters defaults to `BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.bindingflags(v=vs.110).aspx) states (scroll about halfway down the page):

> **Note**
>
> You must specify Instance or Static along with Public or NonPublic or no members will be returned.

The following is also mentioned for [`Type.GetMethods(BindingFlags)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4d848zkb(v=vs.110).aspx):

> - You must specify either **BindingFlags.Instance** or **BindingFlags.Static** in order to get a return.
> - Specify **BindingFlags.NonPublic** to include non-public methods (that is, private, internal, and protected methods) in the search. Only protected and internal methods on base classes are returned; private methods on base classes are not returned.

Therefore you need to specify *both* `BindingFlags.NonPublic` and `BindingFlags.Instance`:

```
MethodInfo[] mi = a.GetMethods(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
```