# Serilalize private field of base class without [DataContract]

Tags: c#, .net, serialization, json.net

I have to serialize derived class, but I need all data it contains (including private fields and base class ones).

I'd like to use `[Datacontract]` as below.

```cs
using System;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        [DataContract]
        class Base
        {
            public Base(int fieldValue)
            {
                _field = fieldValue;
            }

            [DataMember]
            private int _field;
        }

        class Derived : Base
        {
            public Derived(int fieldValue) : base(fieldValue)
            {
            }
        }
    
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var derived = new Derived(10);
            var serialized = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(derived);
            Console.WriteLine(serialized);
        }
    }
}
```

But there are too much legacy classes to modify, so I followed [the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24106986/json-net-force-serialization-of-all-private-fields-and-all-fields-in-sub-classe) and wrote Contract resolver

```cs
public class MyContractResolver : DefaultContractResolver
{
    protected override IList<JsonProperty> CreateProperties(Type type, MemberSerialization memberSerialization)
    {
        var properties = type
            .GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance)
            .Where(p => p.CanRead && p.CanWrite)
            .Select(p => base.CreateProperty(p, memberSerialization))
            .Union(type.GetFields(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance)
                .Select(f => base.CreateProperty(f, memberSerialization)))
            .Distinct(JsonPropertyComparer.Instance)
            .ToList();

        foreach (var property in properties)
        {
            var ignored = ShouldPropertyBeIgnored(property);

            property.Ignored = ignored;
            property.Readable = !ignored;
            property.Writable = !ignored;
        }
            
        return properties;
    }

    // Actualy, contains some logic
    private bool ShouldPropertyBeIgnored(JsonProperty property) => false;
}
```

Unfortunately, it does not serialise properties of base types

Comment: Private properties of base types are not inherited (and they are not polymorphic), and thus currentType.GetProperties(..) doesn’t include them. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/2267299/2864740  — tldr; walk through each BaseType.

Comment: @user2864740 Thank you, it did the trick (https://pastebin.com/fAYUh4yf). Could you convert your comment to answer?

Comment: @AndreyGolubev Is there any reason against marking the `_field` as `protected`?

Comment: @PeterCsala as I mentioned, there are a huge amount of legacy classes, so changing them would take too much time

Comment: @AndreyGolubev That makes sense, thanks.

Comment: @user2864740 could you convert your comment to an answer so I would close the question?

Comment: This would be self-answer time! I’m just a link bot ^_^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [user2864740](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2864740/user2864740) mentioned, private properties of base types are not inherited (and they are not polymorphic), and thus currentType.GetProperties(..) doesn’t include them.

So, I iterated through `.BaseType` as [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2267277/get-private-properties-method-of-base-class-with-reflection/2267299#2267299).

It fixed my trouble. Reproducible code example is below

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization;

namespace DerivedSerialization
{
    internal class MyContractResolver : DefaultContractResolver
    {
        protected override IList<JsonProperty> CreateProperties(Type type, MemberSerialization memberSerialization)
        {
            var properties = GetJsonProperties(type, memberSerialization);
            foreach (var property in properties)
            {
                property.Ignored = false;
                property.Readable = true;
                property.Writable = true;
            }
            return properties;
        }

        private IList<JsonProperty> GetJsonProperties(Type type, MemberSerialization memberSerialization)
        {
            var properties = type
                .GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance)
                .Where(p => p.CanRead && p.CanWrite)
                .Select(p => base.CreateProperty(p, memberSerialization))
                .Union(type.GetFields(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance)
                    .Select(f => base.CreateProperty(f, memberSerialization)));

            if (type.BaseType == null)
                return properties.Distinct(new JsonPropertyComparer()).ToList();

            return properties.Union(GetJsonProperties(type.BaseType, memberSerialization))
                .Distinct(new JsonPropertyComparer())
                .ToList();
        }
    }

    #region JsonPropertyComparer
    
    internal class JsonPropertyComparer : IEqualityComparer<JsonProperty>
    {
        public bool Equals(JsonProperty left, JsonProperty right)
        {
            if (ReferenceEquals(left, right)) return true;

            if (left == null || right == null) return false;

            return left.PropertyName?.Equals(right.PropertyName) ?? right.PropertyName == null;
        }

        public int GetHashCode(JsonProperty obj)
        {
            return obj.PropertyName?.GetHashCode() ?? 0;
        }
    }
    
    #endregion

    internal class Program
    {
        class Base
        {
            public Base(int fieldValue)
            {
                _field = fieldValue;
            }
            
            private int _field;
        }

        class Derived : Base
        {
            public Derived(int fieldValue) : base(fieldValue)
            {
            }
        }
    
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var derived = new Derived(10);
            var jsonSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings { ContractResolver = new MyContractResolver() };
            var serialized = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(derived, jsonSettings);
            Console.WriteLine(serialized);
        }
    }
}
```